# checking to see if a video is paused with iframe on a timer(no buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

so i have this iframe here
`<iframe  align="center" id="video1" width="560" height="315"           src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLTbSBTIefRzkA4B4Idgd6C0RRs7IHeYbL" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`   and then we have this function which is supposed to add bars to the totalxp div tag while the video is playing but it doesnt

```
<script>
 setInterval(function() { counter() }, 0);
   function counter(){
         var i = localStorage.getItem('xp').length/100 + 1;
            document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = i;
}
var vid1 = document.getElementById("video1");

setInterval(function() { counter1() }, 5000);
     function counter1(){
          vid1.paused; 
               if (vid1.paused==false){
                   window.localStorage.setItem('xp',window.localStorage.getItem('xp') + '||||||||||||||||||||');
                   document.getElementById("totalxp").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('xp');
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="7">level:</div><div id="level">1</div>
<div id="totalxp"></div>
```

been tearing hair out over this need help

Comment: Have you thought about using google/youtube's API for the youtube player? You will have control over the player events if you use it. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Comment: @NewToJS any other ideas? We cant apply for it.

Comment: You can't apply for it? What do you mean?

Comment: @NewToJS one needs an API key to use the youtube API correct? Our group would prefer an alternative to that if possible.

Comment: I don't think you need a key to use the player but I'm not 100% sure. I have a site using the player without a key so it could be worth testing. At least you will have control of the player and have all the events. I think the key is to query youtube / search. Unless you plan to search videos too, could be worth registering for the key.